# android studio web API controller post

Tags: android, asp.net-web-api

```
package com.example.simplesignalrclient;

import java.util.List;
public class FacebookProfil {

private String ID;
private String Adi;
private String Soyadi;
private String KullaniciAdi;
private String EMail;
private String ProfilResmi;
private List<FacebookFriend> arkadaslar;


public String getID()
{
    return ID;
}
public void  setID(String ID)
{
    this.ID=ID;
}

public String getAdi()
{
    return ID;
}
public void  setAdi(String Adi)
{
    this.Adi=Adi;
}


public String getSoyadi()
{
    return Soyadi;
}

public void  setSoyadi(String Soyadi)
{
    this.Soyadi=Soyadi;
}

public String getKullaniciAdi()
{
    return KullaniciAdi;
}
public void  setKullaniciAdi(String KullaniciAdi)
{
    this.KullaniciAdi=KullaniciAdi;
}


public String getEMail()
{
    return EMail;
}
public void  setEMail(String EMail)
{
    this.EMail=EMail;
}

public String getProfilResmi()
{
    return ProfilResmi;
}
public void  setProfilResmi(String ProfilResmi)
{
    this.ProfilResmi=ProfilResmi;
}


public List<FacebookFriend> getarkadaslar()
{
    return arkadaslar;
}
public void setarkadaslar(List<FacebookFriend> arkadaslar)
{
    this.arkadaslar=arkadaslar;
}


}
```

MY problem is I can't post my model to API controller.  Internal Server Error

There are details in pictures. I need your ideas

```
params.put("ID",id);
params.put("Adi",name);
params.put("Soyadi",last_name);
```

If I do this, I can send the parameters
but I can't send the model 
I can not find anything to write

**Image 1**

[image]

**Image 2**

[image]